# Reorganizing data in table

Tags: r, dplyr

I am very new to R and am having difficulty with something that seems quite simple. Unfortunately I cannot share photos of my actual work as I am working with animal data and it is sensitive, so I have included a fake version of what I have and what I'm hoping to create.

I have a table of data that shows how many times each animal has been observed (collared location data points) per year (table on the L in the figure attached below). So there are often multiple rows of the same year because each unique collar ID# has it's own row. I want to simplify this so that I have the year, the number of counts (for all animals in that year), and a new column that shows how many unique ID#s (table on the R in the figure).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Figure attachment]

Comment: It would help if you provided data in a usable format; please don't provide code, data, or errors as a picture (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272), please use `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`.

Comment: If you read my first paragraph, I explain how my data is sensitive. Thanks anyways.

Comment: And if you read my link, it explains why images of code/data are less helpful. I'll add one: you are expecting us to (a) transcribe your image of data into actual data; or (b) create our own random data. Some people will take the time (where you refuse to) in order to transcribe things for you. And while some might make similar-looking fake data, it is possible (even likely!) that it is not the same, due to `factor`s, `numeric`/`integer`, strings, etc. So what we *think* might work will not. So forgive me for not wanting to work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  #group by year columns
  group_by(year) %>%
  #summarize: sum the counts and count the number of rows (num uniqueID)
  summarize(count = sum(count),
            numBears = n())
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  YEAR = c(1995L, 1995L, 1998L),
  ID   = c(100L, 101L, 100L),
  COUNT = c(4L, 17L, 25L)
)
tmp <- tapply(dat, dat$YEAR, function(x) data.frame(COUNT = sum(x$COUNT), NO = nrow(x)))
tmp <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, Map(cbind, YEAR=names(tmp), tmp))
tmp
#      YEAR COUNT NO
# 1995 1995    21  2
# 1998 1998    25  1
```

(The "duplicate" 1995 and 1998 on the left are row names, they can be safely ignored, or they can be removed with `rownames(tmp) <- NULL`.)

---

Another:

```r
library(data.table)
datDT <- as.data.table(dat)
datDT[, .(COUNT = sum(COUNT), NO = .N), by = .(YEAR)]
#    YEAR COUNT NO
# 1: 1995    21  2
# 2: 1998    25  1
```